# Selection box option issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had this problem while submitting form

blade

```
{{ Form::label('qualification', '') }}</th><td>{{ Form::select('qualification', $qualification, $jobs_list->qualification,array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

In this `$qualification` my full database list is there and `$jobs_list->qualification` is my selected value.but again am changing value and submitting form it stored as number because ex : `value ="numbers"`

controller:

```
$field = ToQualification::select('value')->get();
$qualification = array();
foreach($field as $user_qualification){
    $qualification[] = $user_qualification->value;
}
```

generated html by blade code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="qualification" name="qualification">
    <option value="0">Associate's</option>
    <option value="1">Bachelor's</option>
    <option value="2">Diploma</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Doctoral</option>
    <option value="4">High Schools</option>
    <option value="5">Master's</option>
</select>
```

anyone tell how to display name and id in table same as value in selection box?

Comment: the number you are talking about is a id, use that id to get the name

Comment: but this number were rearranged it was not same as database , that one i tried already
example :  high schools id in my table is 1 but there its 4

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: in my view file that selection options were rearranged so only i had this database matching problem